# Is and how memory is cleaned in cron tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

The question is pretty self-explanatory but I wanna know how to deal with scheduled tasks whether it is cron, `setTimeout`, `setInterval` etc. Let's say I have multiple variables initialized inside it. If the task keeps repeating is it gonna keep filling memory or will it clean itself after some time? This might sound simple but I'm a beginner. I will throw my code here where I send one API request to check the value of one variable and another one to increase it by one. I can probably safely take some of the variables outside just fine but the question remains the same.

```
const { GraphQLClient, gql } = require ('graphql-request')
const Cron = require ('croner')


const job = Cron('0 14 * * *', () => {
  async function main() {

    console.log("start")
    const endpoint = 'https://graphql.anilist.co/'
    
    const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, {
      headers: {
        authorization: 'Token hidden for obvious reasons.',
      },
    })
    
    const query_check = gql`
    mutation ($mediaId: Int, $status: MediaListStatus) {
      SaveMediaListEntry (mediaId: $mediaId, status: $status) {
          id
          status
      progress
      }
    }
    
    `
    const variables = {
      mediaId: "1337"
    }
    
    const check = await graphQLClient.request(query_check,variables)
    
    console.log(`przed ${check.SaveMediaListEntry.progress}`)
    
    const query_new = gql`
    mutation ($mediaId: Int, $status: MediaListStatus, $progress: Int) {
      SaveMediaListEntry (mediaId: $mediaId, status: $status, progress: $progress) {
          id
          status
          progress
      }
    }
    `
    const new_variables = {
      mediaId: `1337`,
      progress: `${check.SaveMediaListEntry.progress + 1}`
    
    }
    
    const new_query = await graphQLClient.request(query_new,new_variables)
    
    console.log(`po ${new_query.SaveMediaListEntry.progress}`)
    
      
    }
    
    main().catch((error) => console.error(error))
});
```

Comment: Local variables go away when the function returns and GC will clear the memory. Global variables persist.

Comment: you don't seem to be creating any global variables. So nothing should build up.